# Convergence of sequences of sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, optimization

Assume we have the indicator function $$I(x) \triangleq \begin{cases} 1, & \quad x \geq 0 \\ 0, & \quad x < 0 \end{cases}$$ and the sequence of its approximation functions $\{ I_{\nu}(x) \}$, with $I_{\nu}(x)$ such that $$\lim_{\nu \rightarrow +\infty} I_{\nu}(x) = I(x).$$ For the above, I can additionally assume that $I_{\nu}(x) \in [0,1]$, with $\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} I_{\nu}(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} I_{\nu}(x) = 1$, $\forall \nu$.

Let $0 > \underline{x} > \overline{x}$ and let us define the following sets: $$\mathcal{X} \triangleq \big\{ x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}: I(x-\underline{x}) \underline{x} \leq x \leq I(x-\underline{x}) \overline{x} \big\}$$ $$\mathcal{X}_{\nu} \triangleq \big\{ x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}: I_{\nu}(x-\underline{x}) \underline{x} \leq x \leq I_{\nu}(x-\underline{x}) \overline{x} \big\}.$$

First of all, can I say that $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathcal{X}_{\alpha}$?

Furthermore, how do I calculate $\lim\inf_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu}$ and $ \lim\sup_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu}$? And how can I verify the following? $$\lim\inf_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu} = \lim\sup_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu} = \lim_{\nu \rightarrow + \infty} \mathcal{X}_{\nu} = \mathcal{X}$$