# Sequence of connected sets converging to disconnected set

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let us have the disconnected set $\mathcal{X} = \{0\} \cup [\underline{x},\overline{x}]$ and its approximation $\mathcal{X}_{\nu} \subseteq [0,\overline{x}]$, with $0 > \underline{x} > \overline{x}$.

Is it possible for a sequence $\{ \mathcal{X}_{\nu} \}$ to converge to $\mathcal{X}$, for $\nu \rightarrow \infty$? If yes, what are the steps to prove it?

I hope I'm providing enough information.

Comment: Is it required that all $\mathcal{X}_\nu$ are connected, and only the limit is disconnected?

Comment: Yes. If you want more details, you can take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694886/convergence-of-sequences-of-sets

Comment: I would say the answer is "no", it's not possible.  Since each $\mathcal{X}_\nu$ is connected and contains 0, you would have to have a limit of points all 0 which converge to a positive value.  This isn't a proof, just an intuition.

Comment: What do you mean by "converge"? Is it convergence with respect to the Hausdorff metric, for example?

Comment: Well, $\mathcal{X}$ doesn't have to contain 0 (but of course it can). Actually, in my particular problem, I have $\mathcal{X}_{\nu} \triangleq \big\{ x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}: I_{\nu}(x) \underline{x} \leq x \leq I_{\nu}(x) \overline{x} \big\}$, where $I_{\nu}$ is a logistic function (approximation of the indicator function).

Comment: @Etienne, I meant Painleve-Kuratowski convergence, but I guess Hausdorff convergence would be the same since the sequence is bounded (I'm new to this concepts, so please me correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @ItaAtz So this means that $\limsup\mathcal X_\nu=\mathcal X=\liminf\mathcal X_\nu$, just like here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Painlevé-Kuratowski_Convergence ?

Comment: @Etienne Yes, I'd like to prove that.

Comment: It's not possible with $\mathcal X=\{ 0\}\cup [\underline x,\overline x]$. Since this set $\mathcal X$ contains $0$ and $\overline x$, you should have that $0$ and $\overline x$ belong to $\liminf\mathcal X_\nu$, i.e. belong to $\mathcal X_\nu$ for all but finitely many $\nu$. Since you want the $\mathcal X_\nu$ to be intervals contained in $[0,\overline x]$, they should be all equal to $[0,\overline x]$, except finitely many of them. But this forces $\mathcal X=[0,\overline x]$ as well.

Comment: @Etienne If you have the book "Variational Analysis" by Rockafeller and Wets, there's an example given in Figure 4-7 that states that a sequence of sets riddled with holes can converge to a set without holes as long as the holes get finer and finer (and thus vanish in the limit). Isn't this somehow similar to my case where there are no holes but in the limit?

Comment: But it is somehow in the other way round: no holes in the limit, but holes before. Moreover, dimension 1 is quite special since you know exactly what the connected sets are.

Comment: I know what you mean, and I'm afraid you're right. But consider the following (somehow equivalent) example with functions. The indicator function $I(x)$ can assume only the discrete values $\{0,1\}$, whereas the logistic function $L(x,\alpha) \triangleq 1 / \big( 1+\exp(-\alpha x) \big)$ can assume values in $[0,1]$ and $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow + \infty} L(x,\alpha) = I(x)$: why cannot be the same for sets?

Comment: Well, I would say that it is how life is going on.

Comment: @Etienne what if we consider the limit as defined in Def. 4.1 of Rockafeller&Wets, i.e., including the closure (see also the deinition in Exercize 4.2(b) in the same book)? In this case, we may say that "for each $x \in \mathcal{X} = \{0\} \cup [\underline{x},\overline{x}]$, there is a $x_{\nu} \in \mathcal{X}_{\nu} \subseteq [0,\overline{x}]$ such that $x_{\nu} \to x$," right?

Comment: @Ita Atz Even in this sense, you will not find *intervals* $\mathcal X_\nu$ converging to $\mathcal X=\{ 0\}\cup [\underline x,\overline x]$.